# visual studio express 2017 "unable to create directory. Access to the path is denied"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-express, build-error

I using visual studio 2017 express, I'm completely new to Visual Studio and I'm trying to build a very simple c++ project that a friend gave me from their computer. I changed all the platform toolset, the sdk version and the output directory on every configuration but it still tells me MSB3191 "unable to create directory "C:...\CMakeFiles" access to path ... is denied" and gives the OLD path on my friends computer.

I read in a separate thread that someone solved this by changing the output file in the linker section of the properties, but no such 'linker' tab appears in my properties window - i can't find it anywhere - maybe it's not in VS express 2017?

How can I change this? If i need to change the output file in the linker tab, where is it?

Comment: If it is a CMake Project you should not be changing settings inside of Visual Studio. Instead regenerate the project with CMake. The old CMake generated project will only work if you have the same paths as the previous computer, regenerating should fix that.

Comment: thanks, that's good to know. But, how do i regenerate with cmake?

Comment: Open project file ending in .vcxproj. It's an XML file so you can edit in in any text editor. Search for the path that gives an error in that file and replace with your path

Comment: Did you install CMake?

Comment: A project generated with CMake will have a dependency on CMake.

Comment: i just installed cmake and im reading about it, though i don't yet understand what it is. does visual studio have built in cmake features? im still not sure how i can get this project to compile

Comment: Before you post, summarize the problem and provide details and example for that to describe what you’ve tried.